# Select everything expect a word with spaces using regex without multiline

Tags: regex, text, regex-negation, multiline, regexp-replace

I try to filter a text with a regex. The program I use can **only replace text** with a regex pattern.
So I have to generate a regex that will select everything except a specific pattern/word with spaces and I will replace it with nothing (empty).
Unfortunately, the program only uses regex **without the multiline option**

Goal:

- filter a text to get specific words

My limitations:

- only regex with replace available
- no multiline

Example Text:

```
ABC 11
ABC 1/10
ABC 1/20
ABC 1/20
ABC 2/10
ABC 2/20
ABC 2/30
ABC 2/40

FULLTEXT
Other Full Text
```

I want to select everything expect:

```
ABC 11
ABC 2/10
ABC 2/20
ABC 2/30
ABC 2/40
```

The pattern with multiline looks like this:

```
/^((?!ABC 11|ABC 2\/[0-9][0-9]).)*$/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/l2zvMX/1

But I search for one without the "/gm". Only "/g"

Best regards,
ElGammler

Comment: Are you sure `^` and `$` are not already matching start/end of lines? Does `(?m)^(?:(?!ABC 11|ABC 2\/[0-9][0-9]).)*$` work? If not, try `(?<=^|\n)((?!ABC 11|ABC 2\/[0-9][0-9]).)*(?=\n|$)`, or better, `(?<=^|\n)(?!.*ABC (?:11|2\/[0-9]{2})).*(?=\n|$)`

Comment: Thank you a lot. `(?m)^(?:(?!ABC 11|ABC 2\/[0-9][0-9]).)*$` did the trick for me.

Comment: So what worked for you? Please let know which pattern to post and explain.

Comment: The program, which process the regex was a little bit special.  `(?m)^(?:(?!ABC 11|ABC 2\/[0-9][0-9]).)*$` worked for me. With `(?<=^|\n)((?!ABC 11|ABC 2\/[0-9][0-9]).)*(?=\n|$)` it only deleted the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?m)^(?:(?!ABC 11|ABC 2\/[0-9][0-9]).)*$
```

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - a multiline flag that makes `^` match start of any line and `$` to match any line end
- `^` - line start
- `(?:(?!ABC 11|ABC 2\/[0-9][0-9]).)*` - any one char, zero or more repetitions, as many as possible, that does not start the `ABC 11` char sequence or `ABC 2\/[0-9][0-9]` pattern: `ABC 2/` and then any two digits
- `$` - line end.